# Android How to refresh ListView on Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have an app with navigatoin tabs handled in fragments. One of my fragments contains a listview. However, the listview don't refresh. DatabaseManager have add or cursor operations. DatabaseManager and Gelirler different class.

DatabaseManager.java

```
public class DatabaseManager {

  private DatabaseHelper helper;
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private Context context;
  private Gelirler gelir;

public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

}

public Cursor sorgulaGelirler() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseContract.Gelir.TABLE_NAME, DatabaseContract.Gelir.FULL_PROJECTION, null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}

public void ekleGelir(float tutar, String aciklama) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();   

    ContentValues satir = new ContentValues();
    satir.put("tutar", tutar);
    satir.put("aciklama", aciklama);

    db.insert(DatabaseContract.Gelir.TABLE_NAME, null, satir);

    //presumably here refresh code. Example;
    //Gelirler gelirler = new Gelirler();
    //gelirler.refresh();
    }
}
```

Gelirler.java

```
public class Gelirler extends Fragment{


private DatabaseManager manager;
public SimpleCursorAdapter adapterGelir;
private Cursor cursorGelir;
private DatabaseHelper helper;


private ViewGroup root;

public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    Gelirler f = new Gelirler();
    return f;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.gelirler, null);


    String[] from_gelir = DatabaseContract.Gelir.from_gelir;
    int[] to_list = DatabaseContract.Gelir.to_list;

    manager = new DatabaseManager(this.getActivity());
    cursorGelir = manager.sorgulaGelirler();

    adapterGelir = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list, cursorGelir, from_gelir, to_list, 0);

    ListView listGelir = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.hadi);
    listGelir.setAdapter(adapterGelir);

    return root;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void refresh(){
    //manager = new DatabaseManager(this.getActivity());
    //cursorGelir = manager.sorgulaGelirler();
    //cursorGelir.requery();
    adapterGelir.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: if something in your database changed you need to re-query and give the new cursor

Comment: When Use cursorGelir.requery(); error program. Write log databaseLocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After any database operation do:

```
ekleGelir(); //database operation
Cursor cursor = manager.sorgulaGelirler();
adapterGelir.changeCursor(cursor);
```

Comment: Call method guncelle();

Comment: You can't do that here. Where are you calling `ekleGelir()`? If it is at Fragment do after calling `ekleGelir()`. See updated anwser.

Comment: Error 'adapterGelir.changeCursor(cursor)'. I tried code in after manager.ekleGelir(); and ekleGelir(){ ... 'Here code'}

Comment: Calling ekleGelir(); in diffrent class. So defination adapterGelir ' Gelirler gelir = new Gelirler(); newAdapter = gelir.adapterGelir; newAdapter.changeCursor(cursor)'

Comment: You must do that in the Fragment, or pass the adapter defined in Fragment to that diferent class. That diferent class must be instantiated in Fragment. Since I cannot see all your code is not easy help you

Comment: In short, i use navigtion drawer in project. Gelirler activity is navigation activity fragment. When user click action bar add item, add data in database. I want to write database operations in DatabaseManager. When user click action bar add item, open dialog. Call ekleGelir(); when save the dialog. Success run ekleGelir() method but listView not update. My different projects, when use to requery and notifyDataChanged, it is success run. But this code don't working now. Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Try to re query it and set that data again to Adapter inside refresh method.

### public void refresh() { manager = new DatabaseManager(this.getActivity()); cursorGelir = manager.sorgulaGelirler(); adapterGelir = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list, cursorGelir, from_gelir, to_list, 0); ListView listGelir = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.hadi); listGelir.setAdapter(adapterGelir); }